# 301 redirect from a rewrote URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

is it possible to redirect a rewrote URL ? Let me explain it with an example :

This page (parameters in bold): 
/recherche-jantes-pour-**AUDI**-**A3**-**19**-pouces-**215**-page-**3**.html

has to be redirected to another one, using the same parameters.

I found how to redirect from a POST or a GET, but not from a rewrote URL and I don't want to redirect from the POST or GET url, because the page indexed in google is the rewrote one (but maybe it doesn't matter, and I don't know about it).

Comment: Certainly that is possible. Rewriting rules are processed one after another, multi rules can get applied if they match. In addition if you make a redirection, typically a second request comes in from the browser which will again trigger a run of the rewriting engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within PHP you may use the `$_SERVER` global variable to access certain HTTP header information. If you want to see which URL the client is using you may want to have a look to `$_SERVER['PATH']` and `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.
See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php for more information.

However, Apache is the rewriter and Apache will rewrite the information to POST or GET variables. If the variables in the urlpath are indeed rewritten, you should be able to retrieve them with either `$_REQUEST` and/or `$_GET`.

You may use a `var_dump($_REQUEST, $_GET);` to check what information you get from your url.